# C++ Restrict or make user input invisible (std::cin)

Tags: c++

I have a function that waits until a user presses enter to continue:

```
std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue..." << std::endl;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
std::cin.clear();
```

It works fine, but it allows the user to type anything on the console line before pressing enter. It's not a big deal but it looks kind of ugly. Was just wondering if there was a way to make the input invisible or just ignore any keystroke except enter? Needs to work cross-platform so some of the solutions I've found won't work.

Thanks

Comment: Print `'\r` (returning to the front of the line), reprint your entire line (or a space, since you've already newlined), and then any simulated "accepted input" if you wish.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you're saying. Where would I print the return character so that the user input is deleted?

Comment: Basically printing `\r` (a carriage return) will put your output back to the start of the line. If you want to clear the text on that line, you'll have to overwrite them (either with the previous/new input or with spaces).

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be just to clear the console then reprint everything again.

```
std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue..." << std::endl;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
std::cin.clear();

clearScreenFunc();
displayOldInformation();
displayNewInformation();
```

Also about clearing the screen, you could use a combination of output characters to clear the screen, or the platform-specific options, both work and look clean if you do it right. E.G. :

```
void clearScreenFunc()
{
#if defined _WIN32
    system("cls");
#elif defined (__LINUX__) || defined(__gnu_linux__) || defined(__linux__)
    system("clear");
#elif defined (__APPLE__)
    system("clear");
#endif
}
```